# Dockerfile: ADD where <src> is URL creates a directory instead of the downloaded file

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV HUGO_VERSION 0.26
ENV HUGO_BINARY hugo_${HUGO_VERSION}_linux-64bit

# Install node
RUN apk add --update \
        git py-pygments tar \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Download and Install hugo
ADD https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases/download/v${HUGO_VERSION}/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz /tmp/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf /tmp/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin/ \
        && rm /tmp/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz
```

and I got:

```
tar (child): /tmp/hugo_0.26_linux-64bit.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

I found a StackExchange thread with the same problem & understand from [Docker ADD documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) that

> you cannot `ADD ../something /something`, because the first step of a `docker build` is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

However, I read it carefully several times that

> If `<src>` is a URL and `<dest>` does not end with a trailing slash, then a file is downloaded from the URL and copied to `<dest>`.
>
> If `<src>` is a URL and `<dest>` does end with a trailing slash, then the filename is inferred from the URL and the file is downloaded to `<dest>/<filename>`.

and in my case I don't have trailing slash. I tried setting the `<src>` to `/tmp/` like this

```
ADD https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases/download/v${HUGO_VERSION}/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz /tmp/
RUN tar xzf /tmp/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin/ \
        && rm /tmp/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz
```

I got:

```
tar (child): /tmp/hugo_0.26_linux-64bit.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

I'm confused. Did I miss something? I'm using macOS 10.12.6 with

```
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e
docker-machine version 0.12.0, build 45c69ad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your Dockerfile to add an `ls -Rlh /tmp` before the tar and saw this:

```
Step 5/5 : RUN ls -Rlh /tmp/ && tar xzf /tmp/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin/         && rm /tmp/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz
 ---> Running in deea1f3a4b1a
/tmp/:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Aug 10 05:25 hugo_0.26_linux-64bit.tar.gz

/tmp/hugo_0.26_linux-64bit.tar.gz:
total 11976
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       10.2K Jun 17 08:06 LICENSE.md
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        6.2K Jul 18 08:50 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       11.7M Aug  7 07:09 hugo
```

So, it seems, Docker recognised that the file is a tarball and did the extraction for you. You could probably do just:

```
# Download and Install hugo
ADD https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases/download/v${HUGO_VERSION}/${HUGO_BINARY}.tar.gz /usr/local/bin/
```

Which gives me this:

```
Step 5/5 : RUN ls -Rlh /usr/local/bin/
 ---> Running in 6f6cabfbbde8
/usr/local/bin/:
total 47596
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       10.2K Jun 17 08:06 LICENSE.md
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        6.2K Jul 18 08:50 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       11.7M Aug  7 07:09 hugo
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       34.8M Jul 21 18:20 node
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          38 Jul 21 18:20 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          38 Jul 21 18:20 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          18 Jul 21 18:21 yarn -> /opt/yarn/bin/yarn
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          18 Jul 21 18:21 yarnpkg -> /opt/yarn/bin/yarn
```

This does seem to contradict the docs:

> - If `<src>` is a *local* tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a
>     directory. Resources from *remote* URLs are not decompressed.

Comment: Thanks for answering this quickly. So do you think it's okay & safe to download it directly to `/usr/local/bin/`? Do you think this behaviour will continue or they'll follow the docs and fix this?

Comment: @Dida I think you should file a bug report - either they'll fix the docs or the code. At any rate, I could reproduce this behaviour on both Linux and Mac.